# Internal library component not rendering

Tags: angular

I am currently updating an internal library that exported services exclusively until now. No Angular modules were exported by the lib. Instead, the consumer app would have to provide the services.

We now need to export components from this lib. I updated the lib's public-api and it exports Angular modules. These modules declare and export several components, but none of these components are rendered when I use their selector in our app templates.

I'm importing the lib modules like so

```
import { LibModule } from 'lib'
// Other imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Some feature components
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    // Possibly some other modules
    LibModule
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule{}
```

The Angular Language Service shows no error when using the selector.

The app compiles with no error. The DevTools console shows no error.

Inspecting elements shows this, with no additional content.

```
<lib-component _ngcontent-ybk-c864="" class="ng-star-inserted" style=""></lib-component>
```

I have trouble knowing what direction I should be taking given the fact that I have no clue what is going wrong...

Comment: May be problem in some css rules? height or width?

Comment: Dimensions are 1240x0... Hadn't noticed that yet, i'll look into it. But since ngOnInit() code isn't executed, I think something else is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this could help anyone.

I had to symlink the built library to the project using [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link) so the angular compiler would recompile the library each time I would serve the app.